# Подскажите css свойство, которое обрезает текст

Tags: html, css

Привет! Подскажите пожалуйста тег в css, который обрезает текст, оставляя определенное кол-во символов и добавляет в конец ... (многоточие).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: А как указать размер обрезаемого текста? Мне допустим нужно из 9 строк оставить только 3. Кол-вол символов я знаю.

Comment: Нужно указывать размеры блока, в котором находится текст, и все что не помещается, обрежется